# See what song is playing on OMXPlayer

Tags: python, python-3

Currently i use the following command to play an audio file

```
os.system('omxplayer -o local --vol 600 --loop /home/pi/sound/homescreen_audio.mp3 &')
```

This is in my python code. My question here is if i can run a command to see which file is being played by the omxplayer so i can use it in an if statement. Maybe something like this:

```
variable = subprocess.check_output(['omxplayer --current song'])
if variable == homescreen_audio.mp3:
```

Comment: Wrong question, maybe there is another solution for your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you should be able to get the URI of the currently playing media by talking to OMXPlayer via [D-Bus](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus/).  Fortunately there are several Python libraries available for you, such as [python-omxplayer-wrapper](https://github.com/willprice/python-omxplayer-wrapper) which you can either `git clone` from github or install using `pip install omxplayer-wrapper`.  That library has some nice [examples](https://python-omxplayer-wrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which should let you work out how to get it all set up.

Once the media is playing, it looks like you can call one of

```
player.metadata()
player.get_source()
```

to retrieve information about what is playing.